# Windows 10 won't boot to safe mode

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

I need to boot my copy of Windows 10 in Safe Mode. I have a regular copy of Windows 10 with the Anniversary Update (v. 1607 - b. 14393.576)

I have tried the old-fashion F8 & Shift-F8 which doesn't do anything. Done this from both a restart and cold-boot.

I tried the newer Shift-Restart & also Settings-> Recovery -> Advanced Startup -- both of these only give me the option to shut down.

Any ideas on what to try next or why this might be happening?

Comment: I also enabled legacy boot options (bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy) already.

Comment: Are you able to boot into Windows normally, or is something preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Booting normal is fine - I'm actually having difficultly with the CPU profiler in Visual Studio and I need to find out if some background process is interfering.

Comment: There are a few different methods that can potentially get you there.  Take a few minutes to read through this tutorial:  [How to Start Windows 10 in Safe Mode](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-safe-mode-start-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to boot into Windows 10 normally, you can use `msconfig` to set your next boot session to Safe Mode.

1. In either the Cortana Menu or from the Run Command (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), type `msconfig`.  Hit enter.  You will get a window titled System Configuration.
2. Go to the Boot tab, and click on check box next to Safe boot under Boot options.

   - Optional - Check which form of Safe Mode you want; Minimal, Alternate shell, Active Directory Repair, or Network.  Minimal will be the default.
3. Click Apply.
4. Click Ok.

You will then be asked if you want to restart now, or later.

Comment: Don't know why it didn't think of msconfig, thanks!